# Is there a web app that helps with a web dev checklist?

Tags: web, web-applications

I was wondering if there is a website that helps with giving you a checklist for your web app, to make sure you don't miss anything!! It could be very tedious when building a large project by yourself! obviously nothing specific, just a guideline for a web app. thanks

Comment: "thier" should be "there" in this context.

Comment: sorry about that!! i will never do it again :)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) is a website driven software that allows you to set milestones, reports, svn browsing, priorities, bug tracking, and wiki's. A lot of active open source projects use it to host their software. I use it extensively for each client project I start.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't necessarily work for all projects, but it's a great start!

http://launchlist.net/

In light of your comment below, I recommend

http://goplanapp.net

it's free and open-source and allows you to create project milestones, have ongoing discussions on various issues, and alot more.

Comment: thats a great site, but that concentrates more on the formatting, and its like the last touching checklist before launch, im talking more about organising priorties, and important features, like security, emailing, error handling and stuff like that, so i dont miss anything!!

Answer (score 0):

I like http://kanbanery.com/ alot.

It allows you to have tasks with subtasks, add  info, attachments, comments, etc to a task and you can arrange those in multiple columns.

(I know it is targeted at scrum / kanban teams, but the app can be tailored to make it fit for your workflow)